# How to make a wrap content / responsive container in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, flutter-layout, figma

I'm having difficulties to make the widgets fits bigger screen when I run it in Emulator and physical device. But it fits perfectly and look good in smaller screen both when i run it in emulator and physical device

This is the first time im trying flutter, and i have made the UI from figma then later converted the design to flutter. it worked well but only on small screen, the moment I tried on bigger screen and emulator the texts and all the components stayed the same instead of following the size of the screen

and this is the coding, (this is automatically from flutlab when i want to convert from figma to flutter). im looking for any help either from this code below or even thru figma on how to make the design responsive and it fits into the screen automatically on any devices. thank you so much for all your help

```
class GeneratedAndroidLarge35Widget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
          child: Container(
            width: 360.0,
            height: 800.0,
            child: Stack(
                clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                fit: StackFit.expand,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                children: [
                  ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
                    child: Container(
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 238, 240, 244),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    left: null,
                    top: null,
                    right: null,
                    bottom: null,
                    width: 327.0,
                    height: 662.0,
                    child: TransformHelper.translate(
                        x: -0.50, y: 4.00, z: 0, child: GeneratedFrame112Widget()),
                  )
                ]),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: You should avoid giving heights and widths to widgets as much as possible since they will not scale well with different screens

Comment: thank you. is there any other way to assign and call heights & width to make sure they fit almost all screen sizes?

Comment: These kind of definitive sizes are only used when figma designs are convert by automated tool. For more information you should check out official Flutter documentation about "Layouts". It is a broad subject, I'm afraid i can not explain it through comments